# How secure is AWS s3 hosting with cognito

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I followed serverless hosting tutorial from https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/serverless-web-app/

This require cognito pool and app ID to be listed in config.js. This file can be read by anyone on the web. Is it possible for someone to use these values and write a separate web/script to create, validate users in my cognito pool.

It seems like an obvious question but i couldn't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, obviously anyone can read your files and use the credentials. AWS recommends some best practices in regards to this.

You can go through the below link for details.

[Setting Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials.html)